# Find Lowest Character Using Binary Search Using C Language

Tags: c, quicksort, binary-search, file-processing

Example TestData.txt

```
Aquos|5@10000 
Chitato|10@9500
Chili|20@4000
```

Output I want(using Quick Sort) report (by subtotal):

```
A5-120-0|Aquos|5@10000=50000
C5-120-1|Chili|20@4000=80000
A7-504-0|Chitato|10@9500=95000
Total Price = 225000

[a] [b] - [c] - [d]
[a] Got From The Lowest Character in Name
[b] Got From The Length of Character (Take The Last Digit)
[c] Got From Factorial of The Name Length (Output First 3 Digits)
[d] Got From The Counter of The Same Number Of Factorial [c]
```

I already code it, but, I confused how to implement Binary Search to get The Lowest Character in Name.

Here is my Code (I confused On FindA Function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct sales{
    char item[20];
    int quantity, price,subtotal;
    char a;
    int b,c,d;
};

void quickSort(struct sales data[],int first, int last)
{
    int pivot, i, j;
    char tempItem[25];
    int temp;
    if(first < last){
        i = first;
        j = last;
        pivot = first;
    while(i<j)
    {
        while(data[i].subtotal <= data[pivot].subtotal && i<last)
        {
            i++;
        }       
        while(data[j].subtotal > data[pivot].subtotal)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if(i<j)
        {
            temp = data[i].subtotal;
            data[i].subtotal = data[j].subtotal;
            data[j].subtotal = temp;
            temp = data[i].quantity;
            data[i].quantity = data[j].quantity;
            data[j].quantity = temp;
            temp = data[i].price;
            data[i].price = data[j].price;
            data[j].price = temp;
            strcpy(tempItem,data[i].item);
            strcpy(data[i].item,data[j].item);
            strcpy(data[j].item,tempItem);
        }
    }
        temp = data[pivot].subtotal;
        data[pivot].subtotal = data[j].subtotal;
        data[j].subtotal = temp;
        temp = data[pivot].quantity;
        data[pivot].quantity = data[j].quantity;
        data[j].quantity = temp;
        temp = data[pivot].price;
        data[pivot].price = data[j].price;
        data[j].price = temp;
        strcpy(tempItem,data[pivot].item);
        strcpy(data[pivot].item,data[j].item);
        strcpy(data[j].item,tempItem);

        quickSort(data,first,j-1);
        quickSort(data,j+1,last);
    }
}

char findA(char item[])
{
    char lowest;
    int i;
    lowest = toupper(item[0]);
    i=1;
    while(item[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(toupper(item[i]) < lowest)
            lowest = toupper(item[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return lowest;
}

int findB(char item[])
{
    int length;
    length = strlen(item);
    length = length%10;
    return length;
}

int findC(int length)
{
    int fact = 1,i;
    for(i=1;i<=length;i++)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    char temp[10];
    sprintf(temp,"%d",fact);
    int hundreds = temp[0] - '0';
    int tens = temp[1] - '0';
    int ones = temp[2] - '0';
    int num;
    num = hundreds*100 + tens*10 + ones;
    return num;
}

int findD(struct sales data[],int i)
{
    int count,j,currentC;
       count = 0;
        j=0;
        while(j<i)
        {
            if(data[i].c == data[j].c)
                count++;
            j++;
        }
        return count;
}

int main()
{
    int count,i,j,n,total = 0;
    FILE *input = fopen("TestData.txt","r");
    struct sales data[100];
    n = 0;
    while(fscanf(input,"%[^|]|%d@%d\n", data[n].item,&data[n].quantity,&data[n].price) != EOF)
    {
        data[n].subtotal = data[n].quantity * data[n].price;
        total = total + data[n].subtotal;
        n++;
    }
    fclose(input);

    quickSort(data,0,n-1);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        data[i].a = findA(data[i].item);       
        data[i].b = findB(data[i].item);       
        data[i].c = findC(strlen(data[i].item));
        data[i].d = findD(data,i);       
        printf("%c%d-%d-%d|%s|%d@%d=%d\n",data[i].a,data[i].b,data[i].c,data[i].d,data[i].item,data[i].quantity,data[i].price,data[i].subtotal);
    }
    printf("Total Price = %d\n",total);
    return 0;
}
```

https://pastebin.com/fJQaFdqY

Comment: Tip: rather than compare against `EOF`, compare against success value `while(fscanf(input,"%[^|]|%d@%d\n", ... ) == 3)`.
   `

Comment: "how to implement Binary Search to get The Lowest Character". Is that a requirement of the task or the way you think it should be done? Binary search doesn't seem to be the right approach for that. To do binary search you need to first sort the letters. But by the time you have sorted it you would already know what the lowest letter is and thus it makes no sense to then do a binary search. So it's not clear how the binary search is relevant here.

Comment: Yes , that is The Requirement of The Task

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood  the requirement. Binary search doesn't seem relevant for the task.